# XML SelectNodes with common values, iteratively

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I have an XML document of registered voters, and there may be multiple people at one address.  I want to SelectNodes for each distinct address (Number and Street) iteratively.  My goal is then to be able to assemble the names of all the residents of a single address into one line.  For example "Robert and Olga bbbbbb", or "Jennifer eeeee and James fffff", or just "Desmond aaaaaa".
I just need help with the XPath query.  And if LINQ is the answer, I'd like to hear that also.  Can you please help me with this query?

````
<addresses xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <address>
        <LastName>aaaaaa</LastName>
        <FirstName>DESMOND</FirstName>
        <Number>311</Number>
        <Street>APPLETON ST</Street>
    </address>
    <address>
        <LastName>bbbbbb</LastName>
        <FirstName>OLGA</FirstName>
        <Number>315</Number>
        <Street>APPLETON ST</Street>
    </address>
    <address>
        <LastName>bbbbbb</LastName>
        <FirstName>ROBERT</FirstName>
        <Number>315</Number>
        <Street>APPLETON ST</Street>
    </address>
    <address>
        <LastName>cccccc</LastName>
        <FirstName>YUJI</FirstName>
        <Number>316</Number>
        <Street>APPLETON ST</Street>
    </address>
    <address>
        <LastName>dddddd</LastName>
        <FirstName>MARK</FirstName>
        <Number>319</Number>
        <Street>APPLETON ST</Street>
    </address>
    <address>
        <LastName>dddddd</LastName>
        <FirstName>HILARY</FirstName>
        <Number>319</Number>
        <Street>APPLETON ST</Street>
    </address>
    <address>
        <LastName>eeeeee</LastName>
        <FirstName>JENNIFER</FirstName>
        <Number>320</Number>
        <Street>APPLETON ST</Street>
    </address>
    <address>
        <LastName>ffffff</LastName>
        <FirstName>JAMES</FirstName>
        <Number>320</Number>
        <Street>APPLETON ST</Street>
    </address>
    <address>
        <LastName>gggggg</LastName>
        <FirstName>NORA</FirstName>
        <Number>323</Number>
        <Street>APPLETON ST</Street>
    </address>
</addresses>```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following.  Most people will use Xml Serization which is not very efficient.  I prefer in this case Xml Linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            List<Address> addresses = doc.Descendants("address").Select(x => new Address()
            {
                lastName = (string)x.Element("LastName"),
                firstName = (string)x.Element("FirstName"),
                number = (int)x.Element("Number"),
                street = (string)x.Element("Street")
            }).ToList();

            var groups = addresses.GroupBy(x => new { number = x.number, street = x.street }).ToList();
        }
    }
    public class Address
    {
        public string lastName { get; set; }
        public string firstName { get; set; }
        public int number { get; set; }
        public string street { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect, thank you so much jdweng!!